# HTML image not loading

Tags: image, html, tags, dreamweaver

I have an image called `flash_icon.png` that I'd like to put in a `div`. When I load my site in Dreamweaver, the image [shows up fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwTzN.png). However, as soon as I preview the site in the browser, [the image disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY5Gj.png). I've checked a hundred times to make sure the file names and sources are correct and they are, but I don't know why they're not loading. The background image loads just fine and it's in the same folder.

```
<div id="mainmenu" 
  <img id="flash" src="assets/flash_icon.png"
  height="100%"
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing your opening `div` tag:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
  <img id="flash" src="assets/flash_icon.png" height="100%" />
</div>
```